# How do you measure the amount of calories with unlabeled foods?

Tags: nutrition, diet, calories

How can you measure the number of calories you consume if whatever you’re eating doesn’t have a label or if you get it from a restaurant? I’ve never really counted but I’d like to start and I’m not sure if you can get that information about everything.

Comment: [Not a very handy option of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter) // I believe the answer to be "with great difficulties". Usually there are average numbers for ingredients though.

Comment: You can get calories for like a potato or carrot but you don't know how much butter is added and restaurants typically add copious butter.  Even pasta butter is often added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can weigh each part of the meal, then you can look up the calories.  There are many apps for this.  If you can't weigh it, then a guess can still be made on the approximate portion size.  If you're diabetic and need to calculate the carbohydrate load prior to injecting insulin, then you can try asking the chef who should have the nutritional information available.